# Display element based on event fired and props passed in

Tags: reactjs

I am trying, to manipulate another element, by, passing props directly to it, and then have it display itself. If I pass `true`/`false`.

**Live running code:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-dan-rt0kj

- I don't know if it's possible to have a system of objects, and based on an event, tell a parent to display a child.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Content from "./components/Content";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    display: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ display: !this.state.display })}>
          Display div
        </button>
        <Content display={this.state.display} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**./components/Content.js:**

```
import React from "react";

export default class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      display: props.display
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { display } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        id="mydiv"
        className="mydiv"
        style={{ display: display ? "block" : "none" }}
      >
        <h3>A simple div</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Goal:**
I want to based on a state, and based on fired event, display an element that already in store of `root`.

**EDIT:** I am aware that, this exists and can be used: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`, however, I am not sure this is good practice, since it requires some parent or some other component to implement the `props`.

---

**JUST Tried:**

**App:**

```
<Content display={this.state.display} content={"Hello World"} />
```

**Content:**

```
<h3>{this.state.content}</h3>
```

It seems the passed in text, stored in Content `state = {content: props.content}` does get displayed, wheres, the `boolean` value does not work directly. Is there something wrong with sending in a `bool` ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your Content Component

```
    export default class Content extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
          
        };
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
         <>
          {this.props.display?(
            <div
            id="mydiv"
            className="mydiv"
            >
            <h3>A simple div</h3>
          </div>
          ):null}
         </>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: In content component react is updating the dom based on the display state. This is what react does. I will recommend you to read some docs on state and props. By the way try naming boolean like this isDisplay. This is a good naming practice.

Comment: Vibhav, thx. Does this still create isolated states ?

Comment: Can you elaborate Your question?

Comment: If I have multiple Content divs. So, lets say, A div has a button with "X" for closing it. It then must access its own state variable and manipulate it, right? So, that's what I was thinking of. But, maybe, instead of passing **props** as generic, I shoud instead pass `({...})` naming params, you think this is better? Fixed naming params.

Comment: In that case I will recommend you to pass down state to child Component.

Comment: Vibhav, how would I do this with Child component?

Comment: have a look I have edited your code I think this is what you are talking??? https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-night-odkqe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: How are you, `display={this.state.display}` with an empty `this.state = {}`, you're not setting a state ? Please explain why this works? I am confused now.

Comment: I see how you did it. But, I need **Buttons** to be in **App.js**, I am sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224779/discussion-between-vibhav-and-albin-m).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this may not be working is because you are initiating the state in a way that does not connect the display props after the component is initialized. This means that after the Content component is "constructed", the state of the Content and it's parent are not linked. This is because the `constructor()` function is only run once to initialize the state.

The best option you have is to not use the internal state of the Content component. Rather than initializing state with the display prop, just use the display prop in your render function.

Trying something like this might work

```
import React from "react";

export default class Content extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { display } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        id="mydiv"
        className="mydiv"
        style={{ display: display ? "block" : "none" }}
      >
        <h3>A simple div</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also I would reccommend using state in the root:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Content from "./components/Content";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    state = {
      display: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ display: !this.state.display })}>
          Display div
        </button>
        <Content display={this.state.display} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Shn, does this still create isolated states ?

Comment: You could always create a second isolated state in the Content component. In the questions example you aren't really using the isolated component in the Content file.

Comment: I know. But, how can one make the component isolated, i.e. so that it preserves its own state. And has its own state properties, set via external props. ?